# How to run external exe under specific account from asp.net web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, external, exe, privileges

Bellow is my code from asp.net service which is trying to run some external exe. It works fine from my Visual Studio on win 7, but fails on my server (server 2008). 
Myapp.exe reports back eror that account under which is runned doesn't have sufficiet priviliges.

```
    List<ProcInfo> allProcesses = new List<ProcInfo>();            
    ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    pInfo.FileName = binPath + @"\myApp.exe";
    pInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    pInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    pInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    string exitMsg = "";
    int exitCode = 1;
    try
    {
        using (Process proc = Process.Start(pInfo))
        {
            exitMsg = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            proc.WaitForExit(1000);
            exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        }
    }
```

Resource pool on the server runs under account with sufficient priviliges and I also tried to use same account in code to start service with those same credentials and still nothing.

I have been told that account under which asp.net worker thread runs impose some additional limitations. So even if resource pool runs under appropriate account, you still won't have sufficient priviligies.
I also found something about using pInvoke and win32 api calls as the only way to run external code from asp.net service. But I don't have any win32 api knowlege nor did I found exples of this.

I would be very grateful for any tip/example how to run external exe under specified account from asp.net service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the account the worker process is runnning under lacks sufficient privelages then you have a few options.

You can either use impersonation in your code:

[WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx)

Or configure IIS to run the application under a user account with the required privileges.

Here is an article which explains different methods of impersonation security:

[Understanding ASP.NET Impersonation Security](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2005/May/18/Understanding-ASPNET-Impersonation-Security)

If you do not feel confident implementing the user impersonation code yourself, here is a link to a codeproject article:

[A small C# Class for impersonating a User](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/zetaimpersonator.aspx)

Comment: I tried the code on the last link but it doesn't work for me. I also noticed the comments about code not working on new windows systms. I guess I'll have to study first two links and then try to put something together.

Comment: Maybe I have problems with this:  <br/>
Please note: The user context that initiates the impersonation (i.e.  not the user context to which it is switched to) needs to have the 
"Act as part of operating system" privilege set.

Comment: Ensure that the account the worker process is running under has the [Act as part of the operating system](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349804(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_3) user right. I know this works on server 2008 as I have used it myself. Edit.. Just noticed your above comment. Check to see if that is the case.

Comment: Can you please tell me where to do that ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Checkout the link in my previous comment. It states at the top to use the Group Policy Management Console: [Group Policy Management Console (GPMC)](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Group-Policy-Management-Console.html) to configure the user rights assignment settings.

Comment: My last link pointed to a 2003 article, this one is related to 2008: [WINDOWS SERVER 2008 & GROUP POLICY MANAGEMENT CONSOLE (GPMC)](http://trycatch.be/blogs/roggenk/archive/2007/07/25/windows-server-2008-amp-group-policy-management-console-gpmc.aspx)